# Can anyone please help me out? iOS How Datasource methods are implemented? and How do they work?

Tags: datasource, implementation

I am trying to implements my own Datasource methods.Not getting how can we implements.

Comment: Could you be more specific? what have you done? What problems have you had? What is your test case? ...

Answer (score 0):

Datasources and delegates are both implemented using protocols.  The difference between the two is that the delegate controls user interaction and the datasource controls data.

This means that your typical delegate method will be called from something like a button click and your datasource method will be called during initialization or refresh of the control.  It also means that delegates are more likely to have void methods and data source methods will most likely define a return type.

If you take an example that has a view controller and your custom control, then you would do something like this to setup your datasource protocol.

**CustomControl.h**:

```
@protocol CustomControlDatasource <NSObject>
- (NSInteger)NumberOfThingsInControl;
@end
@interface CustomControl : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CustomControlDatasource> delegate;
@end
```

You could call datasource methods from your init or refresh method and use the result to configure the control however you'd like (don't forget to synthesize the delegate property).

**CustomControl.m**:

```
@synthesize datasource = _datasource;
...
-(void)refresh {
    NSInteger numOfThings = [self.datasource NumberOfThings];
    // Use the result to update the control
    ...
}
```

The class that implements the datasource needs to conform to it and implement the datasource method.

**MyViewController.h**:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <CustomControlDelegate> {
    CustomControl *coolControl;
}
@end
```

**MyViewController.h**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    coolControl = [[CustomControl alloc] init];
    [coolControl setDatasource:self];
    [coolControl refresh];
}

- (NSInteger)NumberOfThingsInControl {
    return 3;
}
```

I hope this clears things up a bit. protocols are an awesome way to have objects communicate. 
You can read more in the documentation:

[Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

[Delegates and Data Sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)

Comment: Thanks @Gallonallen, Really Helped me